# How to display search bar in NSMenuItem

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nsmenu

I'm building a MenuBar Swift Cocoa application that displays a list of user's github repositories. After clicking on one, it opens a new browser window with the repository on github.com.

I am successfully loading the list of repos and rendering them to NSMenuItem objects. Now, I'm trying to add a search bar on the top of the list and re-render the items according to the search phrase.

My questions are:

1. What is the best approach to display a "search bar" in the NSMenu?
2. Is there a standard way to "search/filter" `NSMenuItem`s?
3. Should I re-render the whole menu (calling `.removeAllItems()`) and add new items dynamically? Or should I have two static menus? I'm asking this because the layout (eg. `NSMenuItem`s) is going to be difference when user is searching and when they're not.

I'm using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.3. Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing special build in for filtering a menu. So I would just try removeAllItems and add them as needed.

Comment: thanks @catlan I'll do that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after few months of trying, I figured it out.

1. **What is the best approach to display a "search bar" in the NSMenu?**

   You can add a `NSMenuItem` to the `NSMenu` and set it's view to a `CustomView` (`searchItem.view = searchView`, connect `searchItem` and `searchView` by dragging it from the storyboard into the controller).
2. **Is there a standard way to "search/filter" NSMenuItems?**

   No, there is not. Clear out the items and re-render.
3. **Should I re-render the whole menu (calling .removeAllItems()) and add new items dynamically? Or should I have two static menus? I'm asking this because the layout (eg. NSMenuItems) is going to be difference when user is searching and when they're not.**

   Having two submenus turned out to be a good solution.